# What are minimum system requirements for developing iPhone and Mac Catalyst?

Tags: .net, build, maui, .net-maui

Just now i'm learning to develop with .net MAUI. That framework provides target platforms as iPhone, iPad and Mac with Catalyst. So AFAIK its need to have a real build system for doing this.
What are the minimum requirements for a Mac, to do that?

Comment: any current Mac that Apple sells will work.  The core requirement is that it needs to be able to run the latest version of XCode

Comment: For example, the Mac mini (model released in 2020) is fine. I use that for all Xamarin iOS work; should be fine for Maui and MacCatalyst.